# save or convert all the clipboard

Tags: c#, .net, clipboard, filestream

I need to transfer the system clipboard between two computer via LAN, does exist a method in c# .NET that save all the clipboard in a file stream, send it via TCP, reconvert it to a IDataObject, or DataOject, and re-put it into the clipboard, without check the format et similia?

Comment: I am fairly certain this does not exist. However, all the pieces are there for you to build it yourself!

Comment: No, that method does not exist in the .NET framework AFAIK. You'll likely need to build your own solution.

Answer (score 0):

To make reasonable guesses about what functionality may come built into the .NET framework, ask yourself, "Is the functionality in question of general use to a significant fraction of programmers?"  It doesn't seem likely to me that the need for the functionality you describe is common enough that Microsoft would have packaged it up in a single method for reuse.  As @pquest notes, the pieces are all there, because many programmers may have use for one or more of the following:

- Getting and setting clipboard data
- Serializing and deserializing .NET objects
- communicating via TCP (either raw TCP or one of the popular protocols stacked on top of it)